# Is bipartite graph genus bound by $O(\mbox{max deg})$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, graph-colorings, bipartite-graphs, genus

We know that planar graphs have $O(1)$ degree.

We know balanced (each color has same number of vertices) complete bipartite graphs have genus $O(n^2)$.

> 1. If maximum and average degree are $O(n^\alpha)$ where $\alpha\in[0,1]$ then is genus also $O(n^\alpha)$?
> 2. If maximum degree is $O(n^\alpha)$ where $\alpha\in[0,1]$ then is genus also $O(n^\alpha)$? (this is weaker than $1.$)

Comment: What is n? is it the coloring number of the graph?

Comment: The average degree is less then (or equal to) the maximum degree, so I guess I don't understand the difference between 1 and 2.

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich number of vertices is $n$ per color (so $2n$ is total number of vertices). I only look at bipartite graph genus.

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich sometimes max degree could be much larger than average degree.

Comment: Still, the conditions in 1 and 2 are equivalent, aren't they?

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich $2\implies 1$ not other way.

Comment: The condition "maximum and average degree are $O(n^\alpha)$" is equivalent to the condition "the maximum degree is  $O(n^\alpha)$".

Comment: Anyway, unless I'm misunderstanding everything here, the answer is no. It is known that expander graphs have genus that is linear in the number of vertices. You can construct bipartite, bounded degree expanders.

Comment: @OriGurel-Gurevich I think that is correct. Is it same as super concentrators in early literature by Valiant?

Comment: I've actually never heard of super concentrators before, but a quick search showed that they are closely related to expanders.

Comment: Let me put it in an answer, with references.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no. [Hossein Namazi, Pekka Pankka, Juan Souto](https://arxiv.org/abs/1208.2130) showed that [expander graphs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expander_graph) have genus that is linear in the number of vertices. You can construct bipartite, bounded degree expanders.

Comment: bounded meaning degree $\leq 3$ possible?

Comment: Sure. A random 3-regular graph is an expander with high probability. If you want it to be bipartite, just replace every edge with a path of length 2.